# SignalR XamarinForms App Crashes When Navigating From Signal R events

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, signalr.client

I am using SignalR to do RTM and RT- Call Invitation, I created a HubConnectionServices class stored its obj in a public accessible static variable and use it to send messages. For some reason, my app crashes, or does not navigate, when navigation is called.

```
public class HubConnectionService
{
    public readonly HubConnection hubConnection;
    public Page currentPage;
    public bool currentPageis;

    public HubConnectionService(string token)
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(ApiSettings.HubConnection + "/video", (opts) =>
        {
            opts.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);

            opts.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (message) =>
            {
                if (message is HttpClientHandler clientHandler)
                {
                    clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback +=
                        (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
                }
                return message;
            };
        }).Build();
    }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public enum ConnectionResult
    {
        Connected, Disconnected
    }

    public async Task<ConnectionResult> ConnectAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await hubConnection.StartAsync();
            return ConnectionResult.Connected;
        }
        catch (Exception problem)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(problem.Message);
            return ConnectionResult.Disconnected;
        }
    }

    public ConnectionResult AddRecivePoints()
    {
        try
        {
            // when disconnected
            hubConnection.Closed += async (error) =>
            {
                GlobalVariables.isConnected = false;
                
                while (hubConnection.State != HubConnectionState.Connected)
                {
                    _ = await ConnectAsync();
                }
                GlobalVariables.isConnected = true;
            };

            // receive message
            _ = hubConnection.On("ReceiveMessage", (Func<string, HubMessage, Task>)(async (user, message) =>
            {
                await SwitchCases(message);
            }));
            
            return ConnectionResult.Connected;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return ConnectionResult.Disconnected;
        }
    }

    private async Task SwitchCases(HubMessage message)
    {
        switch (message.Type)
        {
            case HubMessageType.VideoCallInvitation:
                {
                    if (GlobalVariables.UserIsAvailable)
                    {
                        GlobalVariables.UserIsAvailable = false;
                        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ReciviedCall(hubMessage: message));
                    }
                    break;
                }

            case HubMessageType.NormalMessage:
                Page cpage = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1];
                bool page = cpage?.GetType().Name == nameof(ChatPrivate);
                message.IsNotUserCreated = true;
                message.IsUserCreated = false;
                bool sender = GlobalVariables.CurrentOpenChatUserEmail == message.Sender;

                if (page && sender)
                {
                    GlobalVariables.privateChatMessages.Add(message);
                }
                else
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<INotification>().CreateNotification(message.Sender,message.Data);
                    //CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show(message.Data, message.Sender, 0, DateTime.Now);
                }
                break;

            case HubMessageType.UnKnownError:
                break;

            case HubMessageType.CallAccepted:
                break;

            case HubMessageType.CallRejected:
                if (Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1)
                {
                    currentPage = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1];
                    currentPageis = currentPage.GetType().Name == nameof(RoomPage);
                    if (currentPageis)
                    {
                        _ = await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
                    }
                }
                break;

            case HubMessageType.NewUserJoinedCall:
                break;

            case HubMessageType.UserNotAvailableForVideoCall:
                bool isInVideoCallPage = Application.Current.MainPage is RoomPage;
                if (isInVideoCallPage)
                {
                    _ = await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
                }
                GlobalVariables.UserIsAvailable = false;
                break;

            case HubMessageType.UserNotOnline:
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public async Task Disconnect()
    {
        await hubConnection.StopAsync();
    }

    public async Task<string> SendMessage(string toUser, HubMessage msg)
    {
        try
        {
            await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendChatMessageAsync", msg, toUser);
            return "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception X)
        {
            return X.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I log in:

```
try
{
    GlobalVariables.connectionService = new HubConnectionService("Bearer " + loginresult.IdentityToken);
    ConnectionResult connectionResult = await GlobalVariables.connectionService.ConnectAsync();

    // 10 attempts to connect to chat hub
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (connectionResult == ConnectionResult.Disconnected)
        {
            await GlobalVariables.connectionService.Disconnect();
            connectionResult = await GlobalVariables.connectionService.ConnectAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            _ = GlobalVariables.connectionService.AddRecivePoints();
            break;
        }
    }

    if (connectionResult == ConnectionResult.Disconnected)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Chat service failed restart is required", "Okay");
    }
}
catch (Exception x)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Error", x.Message, "Okay");
}
```

Sending Messages

```
_ = await GlobalVariables.connectionService.SendMessage(toUser, hubMessage);
```

The only places where I was able to pinpoint the bug is when I tries to reconnect.

When I call -> Close Call -> then receive call

At both these mentiond flows

`case HubMessageType.VideoCallInvitation:` block won't execute, but the navigation gets stuck half way with partially black screen. I think its something to do with threads, stuck in these for weeks

Comment: Also Noticed Somtimes the App wont Navigate to ReciviedCall Page when getteng A VideoCall Invitation, It Goes to Playes the sound in that page but the view doesnt Show

Comment: Did you try to use MainThread class to raise navigation work to ui thread?

Comment: I did Try that @o_w

Comment: You mention that "`case HubMessageType.VideoCallInvitation:` block won't execute, but the navigation gets stuck half way with partially black screen. ". What does that mean? How does the screen change to black if your navigation isn't being hit? Could it be your `ReciviedCall` is the issue? Perhaps replace that page with a blank one for now to see if it even loads. If it loads the blank page, then something on your `ReciviedCall` isn't loading right.